# Using visual studio code and running tasks where path to .exe contains a space

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am following the walkthrough from the [microsoft docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/typescript) for using typescript in a vs code project. When I try and run the build task, the terminal comes up with

> Executing task: c:\whatever\my path with spaces\Projects\ProjectName\node_modules.bin\tsc.cmd -p "c:\whatever\my path with spaces\Projects\ProjectName\tsconfig.json"

and the error

> 'c:\whatever\my' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

That is, the space in the folder name is confusing the task runner. I need something like

```
call "c:\whatever\my path with spaces\Projects\ProjectName\node_modules\.bin\tsc.cmd" -p "c:\whatever\my path with spaces\Projects\ProjectName\tsconfig.json"
```

How do I set up VS Code so the terminal recieves an input it can interpret with spaces in the directory name? Thank you

current tasks.json:

```
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "typescript",
        "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$tsc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        }
    }
]
```

Comment: maybe you need to escape space like https://superuser.com/questions/279008/how-do-i-escape-spaces-in-command-line-in-windows-without-using-quotation-marks

Answer (score 2):

Try using ''-s to escape the string containing the spaces:

- in terminal: c:\whatever\'my path with
  spaces'\Projects\ProjectName\tsconfig.json
- in .json: "command":
  "c:\\whatever\\'my path with
  spaces'\\Projects\\ProjectName\\tsconfig.json"

Answer (score 1):

You should use quotation marks `\"` (slash + quotation mark) for the entire command as in

```
"command": "\"c:/Program Files (x86)/Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0/VC/bin/cl.exe\"",
```

or if using backslashes

```
 "command": "\"c:\\tools\\my tool folder\\test.exe\"",
```

Please note that there are to quotations marks at the end of the command (one for json string and one for defined a path including spaces)

Comment: This did not work for me.

Comment: @ElectRocnic I just validated with my VSC 1.76.2 running on Windows 10. Maybe some other issue on your system? Could you give more details? I added the version if you prefer to use backslashes

Comment: Does not work for me either, for context its a task of type "shell".

Answer (score 1):

To deal with path includes space, we need to surround the path with a single quotation marks.

So the command `"$tsc"` should be surrounded with a single quotation mark as `"'$tsc'"` [check this stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68057625/17071589)