# VS Code debugging fails when there's a space in the source path

Tags: c, windows, debugging, visual-studio-code, gdb

I'm trying to create a GDB debugging pipeline for my c files in VS Code (windows). You can find my tasks.json and launch.json below.

Now if the path to my source file(s) doesn't contain any spaces this works fine. However, if it does include spaces I will receive a message like this whenever the debugger tries to break:
[image: Unable to open 'Semester': File not found]

This is because the source file it's looking for is actually located at

*E:\Libraries\Dropbox\UNI\Semester 5\test.c*

And I'm guessing either GDB has sent VS Code a bad link to the file, or VS Code doesn't understand spaces in it's file paths (which I doubt). Sorry but I don't really understand the link between GDB and VS Code during the debugging session.

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**tasks.json:**

```
{
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "tasks": [
        {
            "label": "Build C Program",
            "type": "shell",
            "command": "gcc",
            "options": {"cwd": "${fileDirname}"},
            "args": [
                "-g", "-o", "${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe", "${fileBasename}"
            ],
            "group": {"kind": "build","isDefault": true}
        }
    ]
}
```

**launch.json:**

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Launch",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
            "args": [],
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "environment": [],
            "externalConsole": true,
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\cygwin64\\bin\\gdb.exe",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "preLaunchTask": "Build C Program"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: My recommendation: **Never put spaces in your file paths**, in particular in source files (or some directories above them). You'll avoid a lot of trouble (and you can use `_` instead). Because development tools (notably compilers & debuggers) are command-line based, and commands are unfriendly with spaces (they need to be quoted somehow) inside file paths.

Comment: So rename `Semester 5` as `Semester_5` or `Semester-5`. You'll avoid lot of headaches by doing so!

Comment: Second what Basile said.  Although it can theoretically be made to work, it's more trouble than it's worth.  Every time you turn around, you'll bump into another tool that either can't deal with the space, or has to be worked around somehow.

Comment: you ask about C and about GDB , then you post JSON code.

Comment: For those recommending that you simply don't put spaces in file paths, sometimes (especially on windows) it is not avoidable such as when trying to link to something in OneDrive for Business (where it forces you to have spaces in the file path)

Answer (score 2):

I think the latest version of VS Code may have already solved this issue. However, some knowledge about how command line arguments work might help you understand the cause of this problem.

Basically, shells split words separated by whitespaces and treat these words as stand-alone arguments. For files with no embedded spaces in their paths, everything's okay. For files with embedded spaces in their paths, it takes some extra typing to walk around the pitfall.

---

Say we want to compile a file named `pathWithNoEmbeddedSpaces.c`, we simply type:

```
gcc -g -o target1.exe pathWithNoEmbeddedSpaces.c
```

Command line arguments separated by whitespaces, from `gcc`, `-g` to `pathWithNoEmbeddedSpaces.c` in the above case, are treated as stand-alone arguments. They are then passed by the shell to GCC, our compiler, which understands that we want to compile 1 source file.

---

Say we want to compile another file named `path With Embedded Spaces.c`, we type:

```
gcc -g -o target2.exe path With Embedded Spaces.c
```

How many stand-alone arguments do we have this time? 8! Now, the shell treat `gcc` ... `path` `With` `Embeded` `Spaces.c` all as stand-alone arguments. GCC is confused since what it sees is a requirement to compile 4 source files, which may not even exist in the current directory!

---

As for the solution, **quotation marks** come to the rescue, which is also known as **quoting**. Most shells are fine with both single quote (`'`) and double quote (`"`). But you may want to check out the details for your shell. Whenever there are embedded spaces in the file path, use the quotation. Such as:

```
gcc -g -o target2.exe "path With Embedded Spaces.c"
```

The shell now knows that `path With Embedded Spaces.c` is one argument and should be treated as a whole, which is then passed to GCC for compilation to be done.

---

Now, what does VS Code have to do with the issue?

In the "Ancient Times" of VS Code, it simply replaces predefined variables such as `${fileDirname}` in your JSON files, then joins the arguments separated by spaces, and passes the command to the underlying shell. Even though VS Code performs special treatment when it comes to commands and arguments that contain spaces or other special characters, it doesn't go over the replacements for predefined variables. So `${fileBasename}` gets replaced without quotation.

Assume our current working directory is `E:\Libraries\Dropbox\UNI\Semester 5`, then VS Code will replace `${fileBasename}` by `test.c` and `${fileDirname}` by `E:\Libraries\Dropbox\UNI\Semester 5`:

```
gcc -g -o test.exe test.c
```

The compilation should be performed without any issue, since `test.c` is in the current working directory. However, condiser the target path in `launch.json`:

```
"program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe"
```

GDB will search for a program named `E:\Libraries\Dropbox\UNI\Semester` since no quotation is used, and then exit abnormally because there isn't such a program.

---

To cope with file path with embedded spaces, consider use quotations. For example, you could surround predefined variables with single quotation marks: `'${fileDirname}'`, `'${fileBasename}'`, etc. Several lines in your JSON files should look like these examples:

```
"-g", "-o", "'${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe'", "'${fileBasename}'"
```

```
"-g", "-o", "\"${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe\"", "\"${fileBasename}\""
```

```
"program": "'${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe'"
```

However, as a general rule, avoid spaces in paths for source files when every possible.